# Freebsd local mail, disable mailbox but enable sending from php

Tags: php, email, freebsd

and thanks ahead.

My systems are FreeBSD 8/9, and i am trying to disable the local mailboxes for all users, but keeping the possibility to send outbound emails using PHP's mail command.

My local mailboxes are getting full with junk mail from different places which i dont really care about.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to prevent your MTA from accepting incoming mail. How this is done depends on the MTA you use, but could also be achieved via a firewall rule blocking incoming port 25.

Comment: Is it possible to just remove the service or something like that?

Comment: Kind of. PHP requires a sendmail style interface to send mails. You could replace a full-featured MTA like Postfix with something like `nullmailer`, which is a relay-only MTA.

Comment: i have sendmail_enable="NO" in rc.conf, which as mentioned in the man page should disable incoming mail no?

Comment: I can't comment on this. My answer is generic, not FreeBSD specific, and since I don't know what this config optional actually does (disable sendmail?, remove it completely?), I don't know if it will do what you want.

Comment: I'm looking for some more FreeBSD related answer... i know that i have to disable something, just need to know how :D

Comment: read `man rc.sendmail`, and next time, mention something like which MTA you use.